# Problem in cake baking tray

Tags: baking

I have purchased microwave safe cake baking pan but as soon as I use the pan in the microwave the spark is coming. What may be the problem ? In which mode should I keep that?

Answer (score 10):

If it is sparking then it is not microwave safe and you should get your money back. No change of mode is going to help, it is the material and construction of the pan which is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that there is no metallic loose part in the microwave. It may be of any other origin, not just the pan. And moreover check for the proper neutral in the switch. If every thing is okay then you can claim the warranty I guess.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm still not too sure this is it, since the question implies that the microwave is only sparking with the specific tray in it. But it's a possibility!